# Deleted gitweb folder, don't know how to reinstall it

Tags: git

Since two days I'm struggling with making Gitweb work on my home server machine. I've modified so many configuration files till now, that I've decided to completely remove the Gitweb package from my server and start all over again. I've performed the `apt-get purge gitweb` command and then I've checked if there's still something in the file system that needs to be removed with `find . -name gitweb` command. It listed the `/usr/share/gitweb` directory so I've removed it with `rm -R /usr/share/gitweb`. Now when I'm trying to install the Gitweb packe from scratch I can't get the `/usr/share/gitweb` folder installed in my server. I've tried `apt-get install --reinstall gitweb` command, `apt-get install gitweb`, few times purged the package with `apt-get remove --purge gitweb` and `apt-get purge gitweb`, then I've updated the apt sources with `apt-get update` command in different sequences with the above commands but none of this ways solved my problem. Could you please help me to recover the `/usr/share/gitweb` folder as my Apache2 instance is not able to provide Gitweb service as this folder contained required CGI scripts to run the web app? I'm running Debian 7.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dpkg -c [gitweb-package.deb]` in `/var/cache/apt/archive/` I've noticed that contents of this package does not contain the files I was looking for, so I've checked the contents of `git` package and that is where I've found it, so the final solution is to reinstall the `git` package itself.

Comment: This is exactly how I recovered mine as well. just running `sudo apt reinstall git`